# How to get BackSpace - with only numbers limit in textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I insert this on `KeyPress` event:

```
e.Handled = !Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar);
```

But I don't have the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key, how to fix it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How about:

```
e.Handled = !(Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == 8);
```

Or equivalently:

```
e.Handled = !Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != 8;
```

(As in [roman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1523908/1369235), you can use `'\b'` instead of 8 in the above code too.)

Answer (score 7):

here's how to check if backspace was pressed:

```
if(e.KeyChar == '\b'){//backspace was pressed}
```

Comment: +1 for using the escape sequence for backspace. Wish I'd thought of that :)

Answer (score 2):

backspace key
e.KeyChar == (char) Keys.Back